# USB on the go cable with power for HTC one X?

Tags: htc-one-x, usb-on-the-go

Is there a USB on the go cable that will allow me to connect both an external hard drive and a power cable to charge my device at the same time? I have not seen such a device but I would like to know if anyone has seen such a product?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts, please read the [FAQ], the question is bordering on shopping recommendations which are off-topic. :)